# How to apply unit test on consumer using AsyncEventingBasicConsumer (rabbitmq - c#) with FakeConnectionFactory class?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I implemented a consumer class based on asynchronous handle messages in the queue. This class has an instance of AsyncEventingBasicConsumer class that contains an implementation of received event. This code is running correctly in production.

What I would like to do is create unit test for that class. I tried to implement a unit test for this class using Rabbitmq.Fakes in which I create an instance of FakeConnectionFactory and then I create a publish and consumer class passing the fake connection. However ocurrs an error, like this: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Should never be called.'
"

I tried to configure FakeConnectionFactory with DispatchConsumersAsync as true, however it didn't work too.

```
var server = new RabbitServer();
var connectionFactory = new FakeConnectionFactory(server) { DispatchConsumersAsync = true };
var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();

//send message - publisher
//start consumer
```

When start the consumer occurs on error in Channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer). This is error: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Should never be called."

I think this error occurrs because DispatchConsumersAsync isn't working.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct. If you check the project github repository it does not look like FakeConnectionFactory has implemented any async functionality. The project appears to be abandoned. Without DispatchAsAsync implemented the channel tries to call the non-async method which is of course not implemented giving you that error.

https://github.com/Parametric/RabbitMQ.Fakes